# In c++ how to avoid print message when I use function which has cout?

Tags: c++

If i have two functions A and B, A will print message when we use A. B will use A, but when I use B, I do not want to print anything. How can I do this?

```
double CTriangle::perimeter() const{
    double D = Distance(A, B) + Distance(A, C) + Distance(B, C);
    cout << "Perimeter of this triangle is: " << D << endl;
    return D;
}
double CTriangle::area() const{
    double p = this->perimeter() / 2;
    double Area = sqrt(p * (p - Distance(A, B)) * (p - Distance(A, C)) * (p - Distance(B, C)));
    cout << "Area of this triangle is: " << Area << endl;
    return Area;
}
```

Comment: Uh, add an `if` inside `A`? Is there something subtle here?

Comment: I think we need to see some more concrete code to answer that. The obvious thing would to move all the code except the cout line to a separate method, `A1` and call that from A (printing the line in A before/after the call) and B (not printing)

Comment: This is something I've seen a legitimate use of macros for, something like `#define VERBOSE_STATEMENTS` or `#define DEBUG_PRINTING`.

Comment: @Rapptz please, avoid the use of macros, the world wolud be better without them. Seriously, there is no reason to use macros, the verbose parameter suggested by Paul is perfect.

Comment: @Manu343726 In C/C++ macros are the way to inject build options and do include guards, so the whole language would be a bit different without them. But yeah, in this case, no need or use of them.

Comment: @Rapptz in C i'm not sure, but in C++ I think a good rule of thumb is to use the CPP only to do compiler settings, includes, and ifdef-endif code configuration (Portable code for example). For the other things, C++ has better alternatives ( const, inlining, etc).

Comment: @Manu343726 and it's exactly a case for `ifdef-endif` code configuration, no? Specifically, I see no downside of using a macro here.

Comment: @Manu343726 Consider a program with a command line interface that provides `--verbose`, now consider that the verbosity setting is set in multiple functions, maybe 3 or 5. It'd be a bit troublesome to have to check for `if(verbose)` in every single one of those, in my opinion. But if you had `--verbose` redirect to `-DVERBOSE_ENABLED` then you wouldn't have this issue. Again, it's just what I've seen. Not very applicable to the question.

Comment: @Rapptz that example has no sense, because macros are part of the CPP and they areproccessed at compile time. So if you use a macro, you have to recompile the program to change the verbose settings.

Comment: @Manu343726 Yeah you're right. I'm just tired and haven't slept in 32 hours.

Comment: @Rapptz thats the life of the programmer... :)

Answer (score 5):

How about adding a parameter to `A()`, e.g.

```
void A(bool verbose = true)
{
    if (verbose) cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}

void B()
{
    A(false);
}

int main()
{
    A();          // outputs "Hello world!"
    B();          // calls A, but no output
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have any control over the function which does the printing, you can put `std::cout` into a state where it won't print anything, e.g.:

```
std::cout.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); // set error flag, disabling output
double d = this->perimeter();
std::cout.clear(); // clear flags, reenabling output
```

You can reasonably view the stream state a resource, i.e., it may be reasonable to use RAII to make sure the stream's state gets restored.

If you can change the function which does the unwanted output, I'd recommend rewriting this function to become two functions:

1. One function which doesn't do any logging and implements the core functionality.
2. Another function which does logging and calls the other function for the actual functionality.